# Sending messages from Linux machine to Windows one fails

Tags: smbclient

I need to be able to send messages from Linux machine (Lubuntu 20.04) to machine running Windows 10. They are on the same LAN.

I tried the following command:

```
smbclient -M \SN-3-HRW\ "qwe"
```

only to get

```
Connection to SN-3-HRW qwe failed. Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

The NetBIOS name of the Windows machine is correct (I verified it with `nbtstat -n`).

Also, I tried to run smbclient with options `-W` and `-U`. Nothing has worked and I am out of ideas what to try next. Please give me your advice.

P. S. I wonder if it is relevant, but the Windows machine has shared drive. Linux is able to mount it without any difficulties. So, it is not that the machines can't communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The messaging feature is not part of SMB itself – it is a completely separate service, the [Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Messenger_service) service (aka the "WinPopup" service), which only happens to use the "mailslots" feature of NetBIOS SMBv1 as an IPC mechanism. So the fact that you're able to access shared folders does not imply that you will also be able to send popup messages.

You cannot send the messages because the Messenger service in Windows has been disabled by default since 2004 (Windows XP SP2), and in fact was *completely removed* in Windows Vista.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is some what weird that this switch of the `smbclient` command was not deprecated (not many people run any Windows pre-dating Vista nowadays). That being said, can you suggest any other solution that would allow me to push messages from Linux to Windows 10?

Comment: There actually isn't any that would always be available. The "Terminal Services" RPC does have RpcShowMessageBox(), which can be invoked using the `msg` command -- it requires connecting with Admin privileges, though; it doesn't use anonymous connections like Messenger. And I'm not sure what would be the easiest way to do it from Linux... (I don't think there is any existing client, though one could be written using Samba's MS-RPC functions.) You could perhaps use pypsrp, pywinrm, _or_ pypsexec to just run the `msg` command directly on the target machine, again requiring Admin rights.

Comment: So if you _must_ have this working on fresh Windows systems with just SMB enabled, then `python -c "import pypsexec.client; c = pypsexec.client.Client('SN-3-HRW', username='X', password='Y'); c.create_service(); c.run_executable('msg.exe', arguments='* Hello!'); c.remove_service(); c.disconnect()"` might work. If the systems have PowerShell Remoting enabled, that could be used to run `msg` similarly. But in general, I'd strongly recommend installing an actual chat/messaging app instead.

Comment: I see, thank you again. I have to mull over what you suggested and give it a try. Yes, an instant messenger is an obvious alternative that remains on the table.

Comment: It seems that the `impacket` Python module comes with already written example scripts which have various ways of executing a command (e.g. `psexec.py`).

Comment: I run `Growl for Windows` on my Win 10 machines, and `gntp-send` on Linux boxes (debian and raspbian) There is also Snarl for Windows which supports the same protocol. You get pop-up message windows which can be sticky or not, and there is a `Scripty` feature where Growl can run a script using an incoming message as parameters.

Comment: @user1686 Well, I believe I would be totally happy with your Python solution, but, unfortunately, I can't get it working. For some reason it disliked the exclamation sign after «Hello». After I have removed it, I get the following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_service_w'`. Can you comment please?